# What is the best way to copy entire Assets directory (including subfolders and files) to External Storage in Android?

Tags: android, assets, android-assets, android-external-storage

I know this question has been answered before, in so many ways. But I am still missing something.
From [this site](http://www.twodee.org/blog/?p=4518), I found (I think) the ideal way to copy entire Assets folder to external storage -

```
/**
 * Copy the asset at the specified path to this app's data directory. If the
 * asset is a directory, its contents are also copied.
 * 
 * @param path
 * Path to asset, relative to app's assets directory.
 */
private void copyAsset(String path) {
  AssetManager manager = getAssets();

  // If we have a directory, we make it and recurse. If a file, we copy its
  // contents.
  try {
    String[] contents = manager.list(path);

    // The documentation suggests that list throws an IOException, but doesn't
    // say under what conditions. It'd be nice if it did so when the path was
    // to a file. That doesn't appear to be the case. If the returned array is
    // null or has 0 length, we assume the path is to a file. This means empty
    // directories will get turned into files.
    if (contents == null || contents.length == 0)
      throw new IOException();

    // Make the directory.
    File dir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), path);
    dir.mkdirs();

    // Recurse on the contents.
    for (String entry : contents) {
      copyAsset(path + "/" + entry);
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    copyFileAsset(path);
  }
}

/**
 * Copy the asset file specified by path to app's data directory. Assumes
 * parent directories have already been created.
 * 
 * @param path
 * Path to asset, relative to app's assets directory.
 */
private void copyFileAsset(String path) {
  File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), path);
  try {
    InputStream in = getAssets().open(path);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read = in.read(buffer);
    while (read != -1) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
      read = in.read(buffer);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(e);
  }
}
```

It works fine (copy both the folder and its contents including subfolders), if I use it as following -

```
copyAsset("Folder_1");
```

But, if for e.g. my Assets Folder contains -

```
Assets
|- Folder_1
|    |- Subfolder_1
|    |- File_1
|- Folder_2
|    |- Subfolder_2
|    |- File_2
|- Folder_3
|    |- Subfolder_3
|    |- File_3
```

I can only pass one folder and its contents at a time in `copyAsset()`, e.g. `copyAsset("Folder_1")` or `copyAsset("Folder_2")` etc.

**What path should I pass in `copyAsset()`, so that the entire Assets folder get copied by calling the function only once.** Or, is there any better way to do this?

At present, I am forced to move all 3 Folders (Folder_1, Folder_2 & Folder_3) into one Parent Folder and then calling `copyAsset("Parent_Folder")`.

I tried passing `null` (`copyAsset()`) and empty string (`copyAsset("")`), but both failed.

Comment: do copy recursively, or use one zip file and unzip to sd card